# Apply CancellationToken in dataflowblock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cancellation

In my producer-consumer application. I have:

```
CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken cToken = new CancellationToken();
cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
```

Click start button, the application is running.

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var producer = Producer();
   var consumer = Consumer();
   await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
}
```

In the consumer, I used TPL.

```
async Task Consumer()
{
    try
    {
        var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50,
            CancellationToken = cToken
        };
        var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<AppointmentReminder>(
       remainder =>
       {
         // blah blah for long running processes and updating UI
          var result = Run(reminder);
       },
       executionDataflowBlockOptions);

        bufferBlock.LinkTo(
        consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
```

Now I have a cancel button, I want to stop the TPL consumer tasks while I click it. ***How?***

```
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancellation in .Net is cooperative. You create a `CancellationTokenSource` to handle the cancellation and use `CancellationToken` to be notified of cancellation. To cancel the token simply call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`:

```
cTokenSource.Cancel();
```

---

BTW, there's no much use in creating a `CancellationToken` directly as it can never be cancelled. You should get a token from the `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
var cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. The customer part is still running.

Comment: @Love cancellation doesn't stop item currently being processed. It only prevents new items from processing.

Comment: So is there a way to stop the current items processing?

Comment: @Love It depends on your actual processing inside the `ActionBlock`. You can insert `if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;` if your processing is CPU bound. Or pass the cancellation token or use `WithCancellation` if you're calling async methods.

Comment: Basically it works, however I have a method say `Run()` in the `ActionBlock`. There is a finally block in the method to destroy the resources. The current problem is when the `ActionBlock` received the Cancellation request, it didn't reach the finally block but returned forcefully. The resources are still alive.

Comment: @Love That's very unlikely. There's nothing forceful in cancellation. You either misplaced your finally block or maybe the app ended because you don't wait for completion (i.e `await block.Completion`)

Comment: @@I3arnon, I used `await Task.Delay(500)`, just changed to `await block.Completion`. I don't know where should I put `if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;`. In the first place of `ActionBlock` or after the method `Run(reminder)`?(See my code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63808/discussion-between-i3arnon-and-love).